# Android managed profile - Profile owners cannot set user restriction no_add_user

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-managed-profile

As a profile owner, I am trying to disable user addition and the code that I am using is

```
 devicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(myComponent, UserManager.DISALLOW_ADD_USER)
```

When I call this I get a security exception that says

```
Process: net.notify.notifymdm, PID: 32626
java.lang.SecurityException: Profile owners cannot set user restriction no_add_user
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
```

The official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#addUserRestriction(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String)) says the caller must be Policy or Device owner. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here? The OS is 5.1

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem. The issues is seemed to be although we can can access the method 'addUserRestriction' by being a profile/device owner, we can not pass UserManager keys under that privileges.

To use them we will be needing the `MANAGE_USERS` permission which has a protection level of `signature|system`.
Therefore the application has to be signed with the platform key.

Refer this for more information: [xdaDevelopers Enabling MultiUser](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1999383)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explicitly mentions this now:

> This restriction has no effect on secondary users and managed profiles since only the primary user can add other users.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#DISALLOW_ADD_USER